# How to deselect if dropdown is selected automatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Trying to add few values to a dropdown using ajax

```
<select id="ddwhlprodlcat" class="ui search dropdown" onchange="getSub('catform','ddwhlprodlcat','Subcategory_prodlist');" name="Category">
     <option value="">Category</option>
</select>
```

AJAX code

```
function getSub(...,...,...){
.....
 for (i=0;i<jsonOptions.data.length;i++){
      var optn = document.createElement("OPTION"); 
      optn.text = jsonOptions.data[i];
      optn.value = jsonOptions.data[i];                                          
      document.forms[form_name].elements[Subcategory].options.add(optn);
    }
...
}
```

The above function fills below options.

```
<select id="ddwhlprodlsubcat" class="ui search dropdown" name="Subcategory_prodlist">
    <option value="">Subcategory</option>
</select>
```

The value fills successfully. Now my next function is applying filter using php.

The problem is when I apply filter on the first dropdown. The second ajax's dropdown automatically fills. And returns me the first selectedIndex.

But I want to set the second dropdown only when user wishes to change its value. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: what if the selected value of the second dropdown is not in the new automatically fills?

Comment: Is that filter you're adding can be selected only after the second dropdown already been populated?

Comment: when I change the first dropdown which is already populated, based on its selection the second dropdown fills. This one is basic functionality. But if I want to search only the selection from first dropdown, keeping populated second dropdown to be empty..it should give me results from first selection not the combination of first and second. But here, the prob is that second dropdown select the first value automatically.